# Animate -webkit-text-fill-color

Tags: html, css

Trying to animate the transparency of a text using -webkit-text-fill-color

```
a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  }
 a:hover {
   -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 }
```

I cant set the color to transparent because of compatibility issues of -webkit-text-fill-color and -webkit-text-stroke on IE.

Comment: If your background is semi solid you can use `text-shadow` and `color` for ie fallback

Comment: cant use text-shadow, main background are images

Comment: I think that the simpler solution is to detect ie and edge 14 and under and overwrite the color style of these elements, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have IE browser to test it on my mac, Please try this code

```css
a {
  
  color: #d5d5d5;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(225,255,255,0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #d5d5d5;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #d5d5d5;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*gecko*/
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*IE10*/
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*opera 11.10+*/
 -pie-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*PIE*/
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  }
 a:hover {
  color: #000;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*gecko*/
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*IE10*/
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*opera 11.10+*/
 -pie-transition: all .5s ease-out; /*PIE*/
   transition: all .5s ease-out;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: This was my first approach, is working fine on IE but it's not on Edge -v14,   -webkit-text-stroke-color is overwriting color as expected but since -webkit-text-stroke wasnt introduce until v15 no text is shown. Thanks

Comment: Just. Don't. Mechanically try any known vendor prefixes hoping that some combination would work by chance. Web doesn't work like this since 2012, when vendor prefixes became not vendor anymore. No real browser nowadays needs `-o-` for anything and `-moz-` for anything but some form control tweaking. Please just use Autoprefixer instead.